# Simulating Summary / drill down columns in OBIEE without actually changing Subject Area/Repository

Tags: analysis, obiee, drilldown

I have a  requirement where I need to group certain columns and simulate drill down (expansion and collapse) for them without doing any changes in Subject Area / Repository.
We have measure columns revenues and a two geography columns Continent (values are Europe, Asia) and Country (Singapore, India, Japan, France, UK) in Subject Area.
Continent is heirarchial column. Europe includes France and UK. Asia includes Singaore, India and Japan. We need to create a Summary Region SIUK (containing Singapore, India and UK) and another Region FJ (containing France and Japan). Analysis output should not show original Continent names. Analysis output needs to have three columns Region, Country, Revenue. When region is expanded then Country column should show the different countries. 
Example (Result before expanding i.e. clicking + )

```
Region               Country            Revenue
----------           -----------        --------------
SIUK(+)               ALL                 600
FJ(+)                 ALL                 400
```

Result after expanding i.e. clicking +

```
Region               Country            Revenue
----------          -----------         --------------
SIUK(-)                                
                    Singapore           100
                    India               200
                    UK                  300                    
FJ(-)                                   
                    France              150
                    Japan               250
```

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927392/can-i-create-a-new-group-by-column-in-obiee-analytic-report/14044153#14044153

Answer (score 0):

You can use groups:

```
1 - Click the "New group" button in the results tab 
2 - Use "SIUK" as Display Label and select Country from the "Values From" list
3 - Manually select the countries that belong to the "SIUK" región
4 - Repeat 1-3 for "FJ"
5 - Preview the report; notice that you can drill down to Country by clicking the group
```